# apex:commandButton inside apex:panelBar

Tags: controller, action, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a list of items that I display in a panelBar, each item has a comandButton that calls an action on the controller, the problem is that the action method gets never called!
Help?

Here's the code:

```
<apex:panelBar id="eventBarSeller" switchType="client" items="{!relatedEventsSeller}" var="event" rendered="true">
    <apex:panelbarItem label="{!event.SUBJECT__c}">
        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!event.BODY__c}" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="View details" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" immediate="true" rendered="true"/>
    </apex:panelBarItem>
</apex:panelbar>
```

And the popup outputPanel:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="popup">
       <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopup}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopup}">
                This is where I would put whatever information I needed to show to my end user.<br/><br/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Hide Pop up" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="popup"/>
       </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

And in the controller I've the following:

```
public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}     

public void closePopup() {
    System.Debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Close Popup...');
    displayPopup = false;    
}

public void showPopup() {
    System.Debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Show Popup...');
    displayPopup = true;
}
```

The function showPopup get never called because I checked in logs, what can be happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure offhand, but you might try changing your switchtype from client to server or ajax:

```
<apex:panelBar id="eventBarSeller" switchType="server/ajax" items="{!relatedEventsSeller}" var="event" rendered="true">
```

Server and ajax switchTypes may be a fraction slower than client, but it should processes server-side action methods reliably. The rerender attribute is effected by this. From the VF Developer's Guide:

[image]

Comment: Yes - you have three opening outputPanels and only 2 closing outputPanels. I wonder why this didn't stop you from saving your Visualforce in the first place. Otherwise, try removing your immediate="true" to allow client-side validation to fire prior to executing your server-side code.

Comment: If this doesn't work, posting the entire page & class might be necessary to determine what's going on. Verifying that the correct controller is hooked up and other standard troubleshooting would require seeing more of your code.

Comment: The second outputPanel is closed at the same line. I tried removing immediate="true" but still not calling the action method. Is it possible to have a button/link inside a panelBarItem? I searched an example but didn't find.

Comment: I haven't heard of this. But try switching your panelBar to a tabPanel and see if it works then. Command buttons on tabPanels certainly work. If an apex:tabPanel doesn't work for you with your current code, you can post more code so we can see what might otherwise be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me):

Page:

```
<apex:form>

    <apex:panelBar>
        <apex:panelbarItem>
            <apex:commandButton value="View details" action="{!showPopup}" reRender="myPopup"/>
        </apex:panelBarItem>
    </apex:panelbar>

    <apex:outputPanel id="myPopup">
           <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopup}">
                    Your Information Here
           </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public Boolean displayPopup { get; set; }

public PageReference showPopup() {
    System.Debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Show Popup...');
    displayPopup = true;
    return null;
}
```